# Get food items based on Category (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have 3 tables that is

**Food:**

- Food_id(pk)
- FoodName
- FoodImage....

**Categories**

- Category_id(pk)
- CategoryName

**category_food**

- Category_id(fk)
- Food_id(fk)

My **Controller** is as:

```
 public function index()
{
      $Foods = DB::table('category_food')
        ->select('Food.Food_id','Food.FoodName','Food.FoodType','Food.FoodDescription',
                'Food.FoodImage','Categories.CategoryName')
        ->join('Categories','Categories.Category_id',
                '=','category_food.Category_id')
        ->join('Food','Food.Food_id',
                '=','category_food.Food_id')->get();

    return view('index.welcome', compact('Foods'));

 }
```

With this query I am able to get all categories and food items in my view as:

```
@foreach ($Foods as $categories) 
<button 
style="font-size:14px; width: 230px; height: 30px; background-color:   #00A30C; color:white; font-style: italic; text-align: center; font-size: 15px;   margin: 0 auto;">
<a  href="category">{{$categories->CategoryName}} </a></button>
</div>
@endforeach

  @foreach($Foods as $Food)
 <img src="{{ asset('uploads/'.$Food->FoodImage) }}" /><button 
 style="font-size:14px; width: 230px; height: 30px; background-color: #00A30C; color:white; font-style: italic; text-align: center; font-size: 15px; margin: 0 auto;">
 <a  href="index/{{$Food->Food_id}}">{{$Food->FoodName}}
 <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></a></button>
  </div>
  @endforeach
```

My **routes** are:

```
Route::get('index','DetailsController@index');
Route::get('index/{Food_id}', 'DetailsController@show');
```

Now I want to show food items based on category.For example if category is Breakfast then only food items related to this are shown.How I can do it?

Comment: are you having models ?

Comment: so you can use `belongsToMany()` relationship

Comment: In Food.php I have public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Categories','category_food','Food_id','Category_id');
}

Comment: check my answer...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `belongsToMany()` relationship to retrieve food items belonging to specific category.

In your Category Model, add the following method:

```
public function Foods(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Foods','category_food','Category_id','Food_‌​id');
}
```

now in your controller you can retriev the foods as below

```
$category_name = Input::get('category_name'); //assuming you have a category name in request

$category = Category::where('CategoryName',$category_name)->first(); //retrieve category id 

if($category){
    $foods = $category->Foods()->get();
    //your code
}
else(){
//your code to redirect the user when category name is not valid
}
```

### Update:

**Implementation:** 
Change your default `index` route as below.

```
Route::get('index/{category_name?}','DetailsController@index');
```

Now, modify your `index()` method in `DetailsController` to handle the `category_name`, if present.

```
public function index($category_name=null)
{
      if($category_name==null){ //if no category_name is present return all foods
          $Foods = DB::table('category_food')
            ->select('Food.Food_id','Food.FoodName','Food.FoodType','Food.FoodDescription',
                    'Food.FoodImage','Categories.CategoryName')
            ->join('Categories','Categories.Category_id',
                    '=','category_food.Category_id')
            ->join('Food','Food.Food_id',
                    '=','category_food.Food_id')->get();

            return view('index.welcome', compact('Foods'));
        }
        else{//if category_name is present return all foods related to that category
            $category = Category::where('CategoryName',$category_name)->first(); //find the category having category name given in $category_name
            if($category==null){ // Check if category exists with the given category_name
                abort(400);
            }
            else { // if category exists
                $Foods = $category->Foods()->get();
                return view('index.welcome', compact('Foods'));
            }
        }
 }
```

Comment: I have to make new Controller for that or use it in index function?

Comment: you can add that to index.. No need to create a different controller

Comment: but, won't it replace the current functionality of index method ? apparently you can define the different method altogether in the same controller

Comment: Your idea sounds like you could easily use the same logic for showing either all categories and foods or only some. You could also use a JS library (like a filter) to improve usability. But in either case, going with Eloquent models is the way you should take, as it makes your application logic and future changes much easier.

Comment: you can use the `@foreach($Foods as $Food)` loop in your question's view

Comment: can you please update the controller with "return" at the end.And also view where I have to change or what I have to add so that when I click on any category it shows me relevant foods.

Comment: In views I have to change anything in this line "<a  href="category">{{$categories->CategoryName}} </a></button>"

Comment: which one ? in route or method ?

Comment: @jaysingkar in method.

Comment: @jaysingkar I implement like same way as u told but it gives error "HttpException in Application.php".

Answer (score 0):

You need to have two models. `Food` and `Category`. It should have many to many relationship.

```
// Food.php
class Food extends Model
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'Category_id', 'Food_‌​id');
    }
}


// Category.php
class Category extends Model
{
    public function foods()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Food', 'Category_id', 'Food_‌​id');
    }
}
```

In your controller get the category which you want.

```
// Controller
// Url could be: example.com?category=breakfast
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $cat = $request->input('category');

    $data['category'] = Category::where('CategoryName', $cat)->first();

    return view('index.welcome', $data);
}
```

In your view you need to loop the foods.

```
@foreach($category->foods as $food)
    {{ $food->FoodName }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: it gives error "Call to a member function foods() on array"

Comment: 1st it says "Undefined variable: category".I changes it with $data in views but Now it says "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: $category is fine. It shouldn't be $data. Can you please check all the spellings are correct? Specially where you defined $data['category'].